# Error acquiring assertions, what is that?

Tags: ios, wkwebview, entitlements

I am debugging this iPhone app that is basically a ticket manager that is running inside a webkit view, loading content from a website. At some point there is a telephone icon that you click and calls the user.

When I click that I see this error:

> [assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <Error
> Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "(originator doesn't have
> entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit AND originator
> doesn't have entitlement com.apple.multitasking.systemappassertions)"
> UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=(originator doesn't have
> entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit AND originator
> doesn't have entitlement com.apple.multitasking.systemappassertions)}>

do you guys have any clue on what this is all about?

Comment: I just ran into the same problem, no clue as of yet how to fix it :P

Comment: see my answer...

Comment: Can you add the HTML snippet (probably a button with a `tel:` URL) and the webkit code that generates the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the same problem in iOS 15.1, I try to play a youtube video within the application, I have added the privacy list

```
<config-file overwrite="true" parent="NSMicrophoneUsageDescription" target="*-Info.plist">
    <string>need microphone access to record sounds</string>
</config-file>
    <config-file overwrite="true" parent="NSCameraUsageDescription" target="*-Info.plist">
    <string>need camera access for recording</string>
 </config-file>
```

Comment: In my case, I add NSMicrophoneUsageDescription, NSCameraUsageDescription in my info.plist, the RBSServiceErrorDomain message still appear. And otherwise, add permission of Camera/Microphone to Webkit, that is a little strange here.

Comment: @Gonzalo D. I have already added the NSMicrophoneUsageDescription in app's info.plist file, Where am I suppose to add the above code? I am playing the HTML5 videos within the WKWebView. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: where to add it

Comment: where to add it?

Comment: where to add it?

Answer (score 7):

I was facing same error with `WKWebView` iOS 15.7 when join a live room so I tried to add above descriptions in my `info.plist` to get rid of it but i still get the same error.
While Googling about this issue I found [this](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/702207) thread in Apple developer form and one of Apple workers says `RunningBoard` is one of Home screen on iOS subsystem and `com.apple.multitasking.systemappassertions` also is private (briefly) this is an entitlement requirement and Apple-only thing and there is no way to do anything about it.

I just left it

Answer (score -2):

The [link](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/702207) (from Apple Developer Forums) states to try this where two people replied that it worked:

> Goto MenuBar and find product
>
> -> Goto Menu menu -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme -> It comes up with popup -> Select "Run" - -> Select "Arguments" -> Then Environment Variables -> after this click on "+" button set "OS_ACTIVITY_MODE = disable"

Comment: What link are you referring to?

Comment: In Coder ACJHP's answer. I haven't tried it yet: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/702207