# WKWebView is not responding in iOS 16.1. Live application is not loading the content in the app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, wkwebview

I have updated my device to iOS 16.1. Now my live application is not responding to webview. I have used WKWebView and tried to load URLS. It is not responding at all.

Here is the code:

```
let link = URL(string:"company URL")!
let myRequest = URLRequest(url: link)
webView.load(myRequest)
```

THis is the issue I am getting

```
[pageProxyID=6, webPageID=7, PID=18450] WebPageProxy::tryReloadAfterProcessTermination: process crashed and the client did not handle it, not reloading the page because we reached the maximum number of attempts


Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit}>
```

It is not loading at all.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with a [example].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error acquiring assertions, what is that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69902932/error-acquiring-assertions-what-is-that)

Comment: @koen no this is not helpful.

Comment: If you search for that error you will find many more possible solutions. Good luck.

Comment: found the solution. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Please add the solution in an answer for future readers.

Comment: What was your solution? we are experiencing the same

Comment: added my solution. let me know if you need my help. ill be happy to help.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the response from apple:

> Thanks for contacting Developer Technical Support. DTS engineers have
> reviewed this request and determined it's a bug in WKWebView.

They also provide the solution:

```
func makeViewConfiguration() -> WKWebViewConfiguration
{
    let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    let dropSharedWorkersScript = WKUserScript(source: "delete window.SharedWorker;", injectionTime: WKUserScriptInjectionTime.atDocumentStart, forMainFrameOnly: false)
    configuration.userContentController.addUserScript(dropSharedWorkersScript)
    return configuration
}
var view = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 400), configuration: makeViewConfiguration())
```

Let me know if this works.

Happy coding!

Comment: Do you have a RDAR or FB number we can quote on our TSI?

Comment: Than you so much for posting the solution, solved the problem for me